# OpenGL, translate down on y and rotate on z around ELEMENT center (on Android)

Tags: android, opengl-es, rotation, translate-animation

I have an orthogonal perspective which I initialize like so:

```
gl.glViewport(0, 0, Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH, Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT);   
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);    
gl.glLoadIdentity();                    
gl.glOrthof(0,Constants.GAME_AREA_WIDTH, Constants.GAME_AREA_HEIGHT, 0, 1, 10);
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);     
gl.glLoadIdentity();
```

What I want to do here is have a square start off the top of the screen (at like (x,-100,z) and the that square should descend (on y) while at the same time roate (on z).

The square's upper-left is what I use as reference for the square's position.

Ok, now, I think I get how to roate it around itself. I translate the thing to (-squareSize/2, -squareSize/2,z), rotate it along z, then translate back. And indeed, if I only test this rotation it works ok:

```
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    angle = angle + 3;
    if(angle>360) {
        angle = angle - 360;
    }
    gl.glTranslatef(xCurrent+size/2, yCurrent+size/2,0);
    gl.glRotatef(angle, 0, 0, 1);
    gl.glTranslatef(-(xCurrent+size/2), -(yCurrent+size/2),0);
//omitted: enable client state, draw elements, disable client state.
```

With just this, no matter where I place my square (even small negative values for x and y which only make it partially show on the screen), it will rotate around its center.

However I can't figure out how to add the downwards translation on y. If I do something like this:

```
    angle = angle + 3;
    if(angle>360) {
        angle = angle - 360;
    }
    gl.glTranslatef(xCurrent+size/2, yCurrent+size/2,0);
    gl.glRotatef(angle, 0, 0, 1);
    gl.glTranslatef(-(xCurrent+size/2), -(yCurrent+size/2),0);

    yCurrent = yCurrent + realSpeed;
    if(yCurrent>Constants.GAME_AREA_HEIGHT+size) {
        yCurrent=-size;
    }
    gl.glTranslatef(0f, yCurrent,0f);
```

it will only work ok if my square start at (0,0,z) - in which case it will move down and rotate around it's center.

If however I start it at any positive or negative non 0 value for either x or y, it will still move down, but do a weird spiral motion instead of rotating agains its center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenGL matrix stack post multiplies. Which effectively means that you should do the most local transformation last.

So what you probably want to do is to perform a `glTranslatef` to the tile's current position, then do the translate/rotate/untranslate sequence to effect your rotation.

Comment: You are right about coding the glTranslate to the square's new position first, and then do translate/rotate/translate. However there's another issue in my code: the values I use for translation during the translate/rotate/translate are wrong, as I misscalculated those values and am in fact NOT translating so that the center of my square is in the center of the axis.

Comment: Oh, well I'm glad you solved it, and sorry I couldn't be more directly helpful.

Comment: Honestllly what I don't understand now is why it works (like this). I mean, weather I translate the square down continously or not, the translation I have to do in the translate/rotate/translate phase still remains the same. Shouldn't I have to translate it more each time to get it back to the center when it's moved away for the center continously?

Comment: No, because the net effect of the way OpenGL combines transformations is that they are applied to the geometry in the opposite order to the order you performed them in code. So the last thing you do — the translate/rotate/translate — is the first transformation that will happen to your geometry. That you also translate the object to somewhere else on screen happens later from the geometry's point of view.

Comment: I get it now, the transoformations you call between two calls to loadIdentity are applied in the reverse order. Thanks, you've helped me alot.

Answer (score 0):

*Editor's Note:  This answer was moved from a question edit, it is written by the Original Poster.*

First off, what Tommy sais in the answer below is right, I should first code the translation to the new position, and THEN add the lines of code that do translate/rotate/translate.

Also, the values I asign to x and y when wanting to translate the center of the square to coordinates (0,0,z) are simply wrong, I misscalculated them.  The basic idea here is this. Let's say a square has the following vertices:

```
private static float xLeft = -0.75f;
private static float xRight = +0.25f;
private static float yTop = 2f;
private static float yBottom = 1f;
protected static float vertices[] = { 
        //x      y        z
        xLeft,  yTop,    -5f,   //Top left      triangle1-1     triangle2-1
        xRight, yTop,    -5f,   //Top right     triangle1-2
        xLeft,  yBottom, -5f,   //Bottom left                   triangle2-3
        xRight, yBottom, -5f    //Bottom right  triangle1-3     triangle2-2
};
```

then the translation amounts needed to place this square's center at (0,0,z) are:

```
private float xCenterTranslation = (xRight+xLeft)/2f;
private float yCenterTranslation = (yTop+yBottom)/2f;
```

and the code for translating the square on the y axis while at the same time rotating it along its center is:

```
gl.glTranslatef(0, translationAmountLinearY, 0); //translate on y
//decrement Y translation for next rendering
translationAmountLinearY+=translationDeltaLinearY;

gl.glTranslatef(xCenterTranslation, yCenterTranslation, 0);//translate BACK from center
gl.glRotatef(rotationAmountZDegrees, 0, 0, 1);//rotate
gl.glTranslatef(-xCenterTranslation, -yCenterTranslation, 0);//translate to center
//increment z rotation for next rendering: 
rotationAmountZDegrees+=0.04f;
```